# Split string in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, string

How can I get the string `"text."` from the string `"This is my text."`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('This is my text.',5)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('This is my text.',CHARINDEX('text.','This is my text.'),5)
```

`Right()` will fail if **`text.`** will be in middle of the string.

Comment: you can list 1,000 _possible_ issues, however, there are only two facts to this question: the given string and what the result should be.  based on that "text." will never be in the middle of the string.

Comment: The given string can be changed, what should be result is fact.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like to find "text." in any string literal or field in a table.  Here's my approach (returning the original text to search, text to find, beginning position of the found text, and the extracted text):

```
declare @original varchar(1000), @find varchar(10)

set @original = 'This is my big string and I want to find the word "text" in it.'
set @find = 'text'

select  @original as original
     ,  @find as to_find
     ,  charindex(@original, @find) as start_position
     ,  substring(@original, charindex(@find, @original), len(@find)) as extract
```

Of course, substitute @original for the field in the table you're searching if applicable.

Comment: since you are adding assumptions to the question, you missed the one where @find is not in @original

Answer (score 0):

Is this a specific example of some more general problem? @KM's answer is glib but I was going to say

```
SELECT 'text'
```

I'm guessing you're after something else?

Comment: In your answer, it would be SELECT 'text.'  However, OP said it was part of the larger string "This is my text.", hence the RIGHT().

Answer (score 0):

Without being unhelpful there is a link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/3d9e32f2-5a7f-4d05-b41d-1b469d1a350c) that details this.